# Node express vanity url path parameter with exclusions

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js, express

I originally had this route for matching any `clientId` after `/c` which worked great because I didn't have to worry about static files, ajax endpoints, or any other pages.

`app.get('/c/:clientId'`

The request came in to get rid of the `/c` for vanity purposes so I tried my best to do negated lookaheads for static files, etc `(?!css\/|js\/|...` at the same time doing a capture group `(.*)` to get the actual value for `req.params[0]`.

Unfortunately, I wasn't able to capture the value "up to" the first forward and ended up using `(\w*)` as the capture workaround. However, this only grabs `/client123`

`/client123/item/e0980780-efac-11e3-ac10-0800200c9a66`

but not `/some-super-duper-client5000`

`/some-super-duper-client5000/item/e0980780-efac-11e3-ac10-0800200c9a66`

Please see example here:

http://regexr.com/38vk6

Any insight would be appreciated!

Comment: I added support for dashes and dots via `([\w-.]*)` for now, but ideally would still like to take anything up to the first slash so it can include Unicode characters, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not 100% clear on what you want to capture vs. what you don't want to capture, but perhaps using this would work for your capturing group?:

```
([^\/]*)
```

This would be the end result regular expression:

```
^\/(?!css\/|views\/|js\/|image\/|endpoint\/|style-guide)([^\/]*)$
```

Live example:

http://regexr.com/38vk9

Comment: That was the missing link. Thanks!

Comment: Glad to be of service